# backgrid.js - how to prevent multi-row selection?

Tags: backbone.js-collections, backgrid

I am new to backgrid and using it in a form to allow the user to select a row (via a checkbox) and then click "Submit".  I cannot figure out how to configure my grid to behave like "radio buttons" in that only one row can be selected.  Is this something backgrid natively supports or do I need to write a handler to "unselect" previously selected rows?

Comment: I can see how to set up an event handler to catch a row being selected              `wellCollection.on('backgrid:selected', function(model, selected) {
                alert('A Backgrid row was selected! ' + model.attributes.api + '  :  ' + selected);
            });`       which works well.  However, I would like to loop over all the rows and if any other rows are "selected" prevent an additional selection.   My JavaScript is not quite mature enough to read the Backgrid source and figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick-n-dirty method:

```
        wellCollection.on('backgrid:selected', function(model, selected) {
            if (wellGrid.getSelectedModels().length > 1) {
                model.trigger("backgrid:select", model, false);
                alert('Only one selection is allowed.');
            }
        });
```

The downside is this approach requires the use of "SelectAll" which is really counter-intuitive to the user.  I would prefer to be able to not use "SelectAll" but it is required to get the getSelectedModels object populated.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom cell that renders radio buttons. The implementation below may need some more work but something like this will get you started:

```
var RadioCell = Backgrid.Cell.extend({
    events: {
        "click .selectedRadio": "makeSelected"
    },
    render: function () {
        this.template = Mustache.to_html($("#radioCell").html(), this.model.toJSON());
        this.$el.html(this.template);
        this.delegateEvents();
        return this;
    },
    makeSelected: function () {
        // set all to inactive
        this.model.collection.invoke('set', { "SomeModelAttrib": false });
        // check if radio is checked and set the value on the model
        var radioValue = $("input[name='someSelection']").is(":checked");
        this.model.set("SomeModelAttrib", radioValue);
    }
});
```

and the mustache template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="radioCell">
<input type='radio' class='selectedRadio' name='someSelection' value="{{SomeModelAttrib}}" {{#SomeModelAttrib}}checked{{/SomeModelAttrib}}>
</script>
```